# SharePoint Designer 2010 email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, email

I have an InfoPath form where I used SharePoint Designer 2010 to send an email to a group.

Once a particular user submits the form then an email should be triggered to a group along with the active view of the  InfoPath form should appear in the body of the email message. So how do I display the InfoPath form in the body of the email message through SharePoint Designer 2010?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi Shreyas,

I do not have idea about how to display InfoPath Form in the email body but you can surely embed the URL of Active InfoPath Form. Select "Set Variable Workflow" action in SPD and set the variable to the string specified in the above image.

First select [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%] by clicking "Add or Change Lookup" button and select Data Source: Workflow Context; Field from source: Current Site URL, then same string as it is till Cases/, then select Current Item:Title, then write "&Source", then again [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%] and finally write or copy the string "/Cases/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1"

[image]

In the second image, you can see there is a link "here", by clicking this click an active InfoPath form will be opened in the web browser. [Just confirm that your InfoPath form is a web browser enabled].

You can insert the "here" link by clicking the small icon next to "Automatic"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to promote the text area in the InfoPath form to a multiline text field in SharePoint, at which point it could be used in an email body, assuming you are referring to using a workflow to send the email.

Comment: I am using sharepoint designer 2010 workflow to send an email message to a group once a user submits the form. my question is how do i display the active view of the infopath form in the body of the email message through sharepoint designer 2010 workflow  ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try publishing the InfoPath form as "Publish form to a list of e-mail receipents" ? This will also enable filling the forms through the email itself. But this option will work only with Microsoft Outlook as the email client.

You can always think about having your InfoPath form as a browser enabled form. This would help you in sending out the link to this browser enabled form with the email triggered from the workflow. So the alternative solution is to publish the form as a browser enabled form and then send the link in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer and that is we need to use "To Email" present in Data connections in infopath form designer 2010 and its the best way to send an active form in the subject of the email when you send it to some group. we cannot achieve this functionality using sharepoint designer 2010.

Comment: sorry its in the body of the email not subject of the email